# Deleting entries in a 2D array at specific locations

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, multidimensional-array

I have a (242,32768) array from which I need to delete 2-3 entries after every 22 entries to transform the original array into a (220,32768) array.

In other words, I need to jump over every 22 entries, delete 2-3 entries, then jump another 22, do the same and so on. I need a (220,32768) in the end which I could, say, split up into 10 (22,32768) subarrays.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: Which kind of data is composed your array?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your response. Lets say that data entries are values from a spectrometer. There are 2-3 bad rows after every 22 entries (spectrometer tuned to another source). So I just need to get rid of those 2-3 bad rows after every 22. I've been trying to work with np.where() but I'm struggling to build up the right condition (syntax-wise) to implement this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! SO is not a code writing service. You should have provided the code that you tried. Then, we would happily help you with your troubles.

Answer (score 0):

This is my imagination hope it will work . just try and let me know .(still your question isnt much clear what i understood is this . you could give an MWE (minimal working example)! )

```
import numpy as np
y=a
step = 22
for i in range(3):
    y=np.delete(y,np.s_[0:-1:step])
    step = step-1
y.reshape(220,32768)
print y
```

EDIT: if you dont want to remove first 3 elements play with the step and `np.s_[0:-1:step])`  because array indices start with 0